# Reduction of angular production build

Tags: angular, webpack

I am using angular 9 and in order to reduce the bundle size I have used [angular-builders/custom-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) to compress the build files. Following files are the result of the build without adding custom webpack config.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 emrakna  staff   374K Jan 18 21:05 dist/4-es2015.5e954ba99776a91e2cc9.js
-rw-r--r--  1 emrakna  staff   410K Jan 18 21:05 dist/4-es5.5e954ba99776a91e2cc9.js
-rw-r--r--  1 emrakna  staff   576K Jan 18 21:05 dist/main-es2015.4d301c7da97435dd6fbb.js
-rw-r--r--  1 emrakna  staff   654K Jan 18 21:05 dist/main-es5.4d301c7da97435dd6fbb.js
-rw-r--r--  1 emrakna  staff    56K Jan 18 21:05 dist/polyfills-es2015.41037d0050d584506c2a.js
-rw-r--r--  1 emrakna  staff   149K Jan 18 21:05 dist/polyfills-es5.63b8516dea3f54073ca0.js
-rw-r--r--  1 emrakna  staff   2.2K Jan 18 21:05 dist/runtime-es2015.4de5b9216209bcaaf11e.js
-rw-r--r--  1 emrakna  staff   2.2K Jan 18 21:05 dist/runtime-es5.4de5b9216209bcaaf11e.js
```

Not sure why I am seeing two types of files one which is es2015 and es5. I have added [compression webpack plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression-webpack-plugin) to webpack config which produces the following result.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 emrakna  staff   119K Jan 18 21:05 dist/4-es2015.5e954ba99776a91e2cc9.js.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 emrakna  staff   188K Jan 18 21:05 dist/main-es2015.4d301c7da97435dd6fbb.js.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 emrakna  staff    24K Jan 18 21:05 dist/polyfills-es2015.41037d0050d584506c2a.js.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 emrakna  staff    66K Jan 18 21:05 dist/polyfills-es5.63b8516dea3f54073ca0.js.gz
```

Is there a reason why I am unable to see two types and gzip files when compressed and also runtime.js files are also missing as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration#target

It is set in `tsconfig.json` and depends on what browsers you need to support